# Is there a way to run Flask + React without building the React app

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I am following tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/build-deploy-a-react-flask-app-47a89a5d17d9

It works if I use the instructions and run `npm run build` in the `frontend` directory and `flask run` from the root directory

However, I am trying to develop the React app without having to rebuild it every time

So I can run the front end from the `frontend` folder using `npm run start`
and here I can develop front end without having to restart the server every time

However, I would like to develop the react app with flask simultaneously using `flask run`

Is there a way I can route flask to the development and not the build folder? and would that work?

I tried changing `static_folder='frontend/build'` to `static_folder='frontend/public'` where index.html is stored, but this didnt seem to work, I got 404 error

is this possible? or should I continue to develop front end separately with `npm run start` and only then build and run flask?

Comment: The `build` folder is the same as the one served in development, only it's kept in the RAM instead of getting written on the disk in development mode. If you know Webpack enough, you could try changing this behavior, but very often, people run the two servers separately (access the React app with its URL and the API with its own one) and use a proxy to connect them in development (when there is a need for it).

Comment: Using `webpack watch` instead of `webpack serve` should fix your issue. Edit your package.json to change the command